# TCPDF save pdf to /tmp/ (or whatever the system default for temp files are)

Tags: php, tcpdf

When a files is upload via a form its location is somewhere that is writable by the webserver but NOT in the current application folder. The reason I like this is:

1. The application doesn't have to have a publicly writable folder
2. If you only need it temporally (such as attaching to an e-mail) then this is a great location

Is there a way to have access to this location via TCPDF when saving a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use the very same location where uploads end up:

```
$tmp = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
```

But you should use `sys_get_temp_dir()` and just `'/tmp'` as fallback anyway.

And you know, just pass that as parameter to your save function `$TCPDF->Output("$tmp/file.pdf", "F");`

Comment: Is it pretty reliable that sys_get_temp_dir will always be writable?

Comment: If the server is severely misconfigured, not. In all other cases, yes. It defaults just to `/tmp` most of the time anyway.

Comment: @mario - just curious, when is the file stored in "/tmp" removed from the server in this case? Does this have to be done manually?

Comment: @JM4 That indeed requires manual care. Depending on server setup there are usually cron jobs which purge older files. I regularily set some up for local temp dirs. In OPs example there should be an implicit unlink() in the same script.

Comment: Maybe check  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304553/tcpdf-save-file-to-folder/19316809#19316809](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304553/tcpdf-save-file-to-folder/19316809#19316809)