# PHP TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file the folder exist and has the right permissions

Tags: php, pdf, save, tcpdf, html2pdf

I'm trying to save a pdf file using the html2pdf PHP class.
The code is this:

```
$this->html2pdf->Output('directory/file_name.'.pdf', 'F');
```

But I have alway this error   TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file

the folder 'folder' (the name is an example, obviusly), exist and has the right permissions!

I tryed to omit the folder name, but this error appear anyway...

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is that the *exact* line as it appears in your php? It seems to me your string concatenation is wrong (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304553/tcpdf-save-file-to-folder).

Answer (score 4):

thats because your folder dont have proper permissions.change your directory permissions. 
in linux you will do this like mentioned below.

```
 chmod -R 0777 /yourdirectory
```

Comment: Never set anything to 777

Answer (score 4):

In the 'include/tcpdf_static.php' file about 2435 line in the static function 'fopenLocal' if I delete the complete 'if statement'... works fine.

```
public static function fopenLocal($filename, $mode) {
  /*if (strpos($filename, '://') === false) {

    $filename = 'file://'.$filename;
  } elseif (strpos($filename, 'file://') !== 0) {
    return false;
  }*/
  return fopen($filename, $mode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried al these things, try

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Worked for me!

Jannes

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->Output(APP . 'webroot' . DS . 'files' . DS . 'pdf' . DS . 'filename.pdf', 'F');
```

Try this ...

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer always requires an explanation on why it works and how it solves the problem. Also note, that it is unclear what `$pdf` is.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that **your file('directory/file_name.'.pdf')** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.